# How to remove a timer left over from a crashed script using the python console

Tags: python

Based on this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275122/region-3d-view-distance-not-updating-until-next-modal-event/275125) I asked, if my script crashes while I'm debugging sometimes the modal timer gets left running in the background (I think that's what it is). This causes it's thread to keep a CPU core running at 100% and eventually crashes Blender, I can only assume that the timer overflows.

I can't find it using the python console.

Does anyone know how to find and remove a running timer from the python console?

Answer (score 1):

1. run the script and call the operator from search menu: "XX"
2. press `E` to trigger some error when the operator is running
3. when the operator invalid, remove the event timer from the `bpy.app.timers` or other process

```
import bpy

def run_every_1_seconds():
    try:
        print("bpy.app.timer running")
        # try to get something on the instance
        XX.SELF.debug_int
        return 1.0
    except:
        bpy.context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(XX.timer0)
        XX.timer0 = None
        XX.SELF = None
        print("Operator timer deleted successfully")
        bpy.app.timers.unregister(run_every_1_seconds)
        print("bpy.app.timer removed")
        return


class XX(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "xx.operator"
    bl_label = "Test Modal"

    SELF = None
    timer0 = None

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        XX.SELF = self
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        # Add a event timer
        self.timer0 = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=bpy.context.window)
        XX.timer0 = self.timer0
        self.debug_int = 0
        print("bpy.app.timer register")
        bpy.app.timers.register(run_every_1_seconds)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        print(f"modal running {self.debug_int}")
        self.debug_int += 1

        if event.type == "ESC":
            context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self.timer0)
            XX.SELF = None
            XX.timer0 = None
            bpy.app.timers.unregister(run_every_1_seconds)
            print("bpy.app.timer removed")
            return {"FINISHED"}

        if event.type == "E" and event.value == "PRESS":
            # press "E" to get the index error
            # XX.SELF become invalid
            lis = []
            lis[999]

        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(XX)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(XX)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

#### A better way is to use a draw handler to check if the operator is invalid

```
import bpy

def draw_callback_px(self, context):
    try:
        print("drawing")
        self.debug_int
    except:
        if XX.timer0 is not None:
            bpy.context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(XX.timer0)
            print("Operator timer deleted successfully")

        bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(XX.handle0, 'WINDOW')


class XX(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "xx.operator"
    bl_label = "Test Modal"

    timer0 = None
    handle0 = None

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        # Add a event timer
        self.timer0 = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=bpy.context.window)
        XX.timer0 = self.timer0
        self.debug_int = 0
        # need run in 3Dviewport
        XX.handle0 = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, (self, context), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        print(f"modal running {self.debug_int}")
        self.debug_int += 1

        if event.type == "ESC":
            return {"FINISHED"}

        if event.type == "E" and event.value == "PRESS":
            # press "E" to get the index error
            # self become invalid
            lis = []
            lis[999]

        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(XX)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(XX)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thanks @X Y This one doesn't remove the timer until after a viewport update, so I was able to use that to find the timer and remove it from the console! Running `bpy.types.XX_OT_operator.timer0` showed where it is, then running `bpy.types.XX_OT_operator.timer0.time_duration` showed that it was active. So running `bpy.data.window_managers['WinMan'].event_timer_remove(bpy.types.XX_OT_operator.timer0)` removed it. Now I need to see if that works with the actual one I'm having problems with.

Comment: I'll implement your error checking code after I prove I can remove a timer from the console. So +1 and my gratitude for teaching me this! But I can't mark it as the answer as it's not using the console :( Sorry